# Nuxt How to access router from outside a Vue component context

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js, I have an exported helper function, which should also programatically navigate the router.

In Vue.js I would normally `import router from "@/router".

How would I migrate this to Nuxt?

**doSomething.ts**

```js
export default function doSomething(name: string){
   console.log(`hello ${name}`);
   this.$router.push({ path: "/" }); // this.$router not defined!
}
```

**Component.vue**

```js
import doSomething from "@/scripts/doSomething";
export default {
   mounted(){
      doSomething("name");
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is your helper function located? Do you have access to Nuxt's context?

Comment: If your helper is in a JS/TS file without anything related to Vue/Nuxt, then your only solution is indeed to pass the context as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I've added this as a first arg:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
export default function doSomething(this: Vue, name: string){
   console.log(`hello ${name}`);
   this.$router.push({ path: "/" }); // this.$router not defined!
}
```

and then call it like this:

```js
doSomething.call(this, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {Route} from 'vue-router'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $router: VueRouter,
    $route: Route
  }
}
```

then

```js
window.$nuxt.$router
```